# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Error in my FLASK app server

Tags: cors, vercel, mongodb-atlas, flask-cors

I am trying to fetch data from a flask server that I created, but it seems to give me the **CORS error** and is not working.

```
@app.route('/api/data', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        response = jsonify()
    else:
        articles = db.articles.find({}, {"_id": 0})
        articles_list = list(articles)
        response = jsonify(articles_list)
    
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'website link')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
    return response
```

This is the part where I want to fetch the data, and the endpoint is working perfectly when I try fetching it with POSTMAN, but gives error while trying to display it on my frontend.

It gives me the error:

> Access to fetch at 'server/api/data' from origin 'website' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I even have the cors allowed.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

It is hosted on vercel, and it was working fine, but suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Hey, I'm currently building [blockedbycors.dev](https://blockedbycors.dev) which provides free tools that intend to help fix exactly these issues. You may want to try using the CORS debugger to check whether your server actually sends the CORS headers that you expect. I'd love to hear some feedback if the tool helped you fix the issue and I'm happy to provide any help in case it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so I got this to work, so am sharing what I did .
Now my problem was that while hosting it through vercel, there was a issue that my API was giving a CORS error while fetching the data. It was working perfectly in my local machine but the moment I hosted it, it was showing an issue.
Further there was the fact that the Content-type showed wrong when hosted.

For example, when checking it through postman.. the headers while running on local host were -

`Content-Type : application/json`

but the moment I hosted it on vercel and ran the api, it came as -
`Content-Type : text/plan; charset=utf8`

I tried fixing this by explicitly setting the content type as application/json but it still came out to be the same.
Now to fix this issue, I updated the file structure. My python file was called `newsic-api.py` and it was inside the api folder, so my `vercel.json` file was

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/api/newsic-api" }
  ]
}
```

but the moment I **changed the filename to index.py** and made the `vercel.json` as

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/api/index" }
  ]
}
```

it started to work perfectly. Hope it helps to anyone who faces the same issue!!